# Can Someone help me analyse this heatmap? I'm new to this topic and facing some difficulties

Tags: machine-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAZnj.png)

There is a saying of linear correlation. Is this an example of linear correlation? If not then how can this heatmap be described? One more thing that is intriguing is that what do the values represent here and how can i describe the values?